# need to remove the \ / ä and special characters from the list files using .bat file

Tags: shell, batch-file

I need to window bat file which will be placed in the server path.
Where my all data files are placed in other path. 
1. Once I run the bat file, it should search the list of files in the given path
2. It should search for forward slash(/), back slash(),special characters and latin character set (like ä and  etc., ) in the each file and replace with spaces.

[Original File looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmZgZ.png)

[Corrected file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwryg.png)

```
Aance petty cash - Site 21/03/2019||Y|17-OCT-19|17-OCT-19|17-OCT-19|KMADRZYK|MANUAL W|SAKM18OCT19|S|158 \\fpp01\Finance\Finance\AP_PROCESSING\1_MEN|SAR
Aance petty cash - Site 21/03/2019||Y|17-OCT-19|17-OCT-19|17-OCT-19|KMADRZYK|MANUAL W|SAKM18OCT19|S|\krv|SAR
Aance petty cash - Site 21/03/2019||Y|17-OCT-19|17-OCT-19|17-OCT-19|KMADRZYK|MANUAL W|SAKM18OCT19|M|sd01\Finance\Finance\AP_PROCESSING\1_MEN |SAR
Aance petty cash - Site 21/03/2019||Y|17-OCT-19|17-OCT-19|17-OCT-19|KMADRZYK|MANUAL W|SAKM18OCT19|M|159\fpp01\Finance\Finance\AP_PROCESSING\1_MEN |SAR
Studying and updating dmmmy       ||Y|17-OCT-19|18-OCT-19|18-OCT-19|KMADRZYK|MANUAL W|SAKM18OCT19|T|160 -|SAR
Johannes Märkl Monatsrechnung ----||N|17-OCT-19|18-OCT-19|18-OCT-19|KMADRZYK|MANUAL W|SAKM18OCT19|S||SAR
```

after correcting the file

```
Aance petty cash - Site 21 03 2019||Y|17-OCT-19|17-OCT-19|17-OCT-19|KMADRZYK|MANUAL W|SAKM18OCT19|S|158   fpp01 Finance Finance AP_PROCESSING 1_MEN|SAR
Aance petty cash - Site 21 03 2019||Y|17-OCT-19|17-OCT-19|17-OCT-19|KMADRZYK|MANUAL W|SAKM18OCT19|S| krv|SAR
Aance petty cash - Site 21 03 2019||Y|17-OCT-19|17-OCT-19|17-OCT-19|KMADRZYK|MANUAL W|SAKM18OCT19|M|sd01 Finance Finance AP_PROCESSING 1_MEN |SAR
Aance petty cash - Site 21 03 2019||Y|17-OCT-19|17-OCT-19|17-OCT-19|KMADRZYK|MANUAL W|SAKM18OCT19|M|159 fpp01 Finance Finance AP_PROCESSING 1_MEN |SAR
Studying and updating dmmmy       ||Y|17-OCT-19|18-OCT-19|18-OCT-19|KMADRZYK|MANUAL W|SAKM18OCT19|T|160 -|SAR
Johannes Märkl Monatsrechnung ----||N|17-OCT-19|18-OCT-19|18-OCT-19|KMADRZYK|MANUAL W|SAKM18OCT19|S||SAR
```

this kind of many files will be present in the server path.
So, I need to search for each file and correct them.

Comment: I edited your question to be better understandable, but that doesn't make it on-topic for this site. Please show your code and tell us, what problem you have with it.

Comment: It may help you in searching for a solution, _(as your question is currently off topic)_, that you understand that you're looking to replace strings, not remove them. You're trying to replace any instances of `|\\sdfg\\asa\as\as\|` or `|\asasa\asas\|` with `||`.

Comment: You should use Regex like this : [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0jRFNq/1/)

Comment: Using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) - `call jrepl "(\c|\|)\\[\c|]*($|\|)" "$1$2" /xseq /f a.txt /o -`. Note that `\c` is used with `/xseq` because quoted `^` is doubled by CALL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Regex in vbscript with a batch file : You can see [Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/Dr3ha9/1/)

```bat
@echo off
Title Replace String using Regex with vbscript
Set "InputFile=Test.txt"
Set "TmpFile=%Tmp%\%~n0.txt"
:: To write Result in a temporary file
Call :Search_Replace "%InputFile%" "%TmpFile%"
:: Replace and move contents from the temporary file to the original
Move /Y "%TmpFile%" "%InputFile%">nul
Start "" "%InputFile%" & Exit
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Search_Replace <InputFile> <TmpFile>
(
    echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Function Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Dim strPattern, strReplace, strResult,oRegExp
    echo Data = "%~1" 
    echo Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll
    echo strPattern = "[\\\/\/]"
    echo strReplace = " "
    echo Set oRegExp = New RegExp
    echo oRegExp.Global = True 
    echo oRegExp.IgnoreCase = True 
    echo oRegExp.Pattern = strPattern
    echo strResult = oRegExp.Replace(Data,strReplace^)
    echo Search_Replace = strResult
    echo End Function
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
cscript /U //nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" < "%~1" > "%~2"
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: this is code will move only for sting when start when \\ only. I string might start with \ or \\ or as\sldas\sdnda\ or 123\ \\asa\dad\. it should remove the \ / where it find in the entire file. please help

Comment: @ArunGoWdA Did you test this batch before on a dummy file for testing and you don't get any good results or not yet ?
can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58488326/edit) and post the real file and explain more your issue

Comment: I have edited of my question. I am eagerly waiting for input now.

Comment: @ArunGoWdA
Take a look at this and if this what you want i will edit my answer for you !
https://regex101.com/r/Dr3ha9/1/

Comment: Awesome!!, this is what I wanted....but it should do it for all the  files which is in the same path.

Comment: How do I loop to process the list of files. Set "MYDIR=\\server\APImport\LoadError\dump"
for /F %%x in ('dir /B/D %MYDIR%') do (
Set "InputFile=%MYDIR%\%%x"   ==> it is not working. please help one last time

Comment: @ArunGoWdA Please this is another question; i know it's related about this but you should close this question by accept it as answer and post another question and i will assist you ! You can refer to this question if you like when you write the new question !
See also [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/)
A question with no accepted answer is rated as a not answered question even if there are good answers.

Comment: Hi Created one more question. can you please answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507170/for-loop-not-working-in-windows-bat-file