# for loop not working in windows .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I need a [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) which will be placed in the server path. My data files are placed in another path.

1. Once I run the bat file, it should search the list of files in the given path, (could be in same path where bat file placed).
2. It should search for forward slash `/`, back slash `\`, special characters and replace with the SPACE

[sample Original file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCdWY.png)

[Corrected file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKXxI.png)

I used below code:- it work for single file. When I open loop it is not working.
Please help.

and also file which ends with *.err should NOT be picked from this loop.

```
    @echo off
Title Replace String using Regex with vbscript
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "MYDIR=\\server01\Import\LoadError\dump"
for /F %%x in ('dir /B/D %MYDIR%') do (
Set "InputFile=%MYDIR%\%%x"
::Set "InputFile=\\server01\Import\LoadError\dump\KEG_OAP671A4_55555.txt"
Set "TmpFile=%Tmp%\%~n0.txt"
:: To write Result in a temporary file
Call :Search_Replace "%InputFile%" "%TmpFile%"
:: Replace and move contents from the temporary file to the original
Move /Y "%TmpFile%" "%InputFile%">nul
Start "" "%InputFile%" & Exit
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Search_Replace <InputFile> <TmpFile>
(
    echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Function Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Dim strPattern, strReplace, strResult,oRegExp
    echo Data = "%~1" 
    echo Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll
    echo strPattern = "[\\\/\/]"
    echo strReplace = " "
    echo Set oRegExp = New RegExp
    echo oRegExp.Global = True 
    echo oRegExp.IgnoreCase = True 
    echo oRegExp.Pattern = strPattern
    echo strResult = oRegExp.Replace(Data,strReplace^)
    echo Search_Replace = strResult
    echo End Function
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
cscript //nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" < "%~1" > "%~2"
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
)
```

Comment: @Karun, you've supplied code and told us what you require of it, but have not specified an issue with it. Currently your question is too broad and unclear. If you'd like us to assist you with something, please edit your post to bring it on topic.

Comment: I have corrected question with sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try and tell me if this work or not on your side :

I added a newline to backup your dump folder and its contents if something went wrong!

```
@echo off
Mode 85,35 & color 0A
Title Replace Multi String using Regex with vbscript into Folder with text files
Set "Source_Folder=\\server01\Import\LoadError\dump"
Set "Backup_Folder=%userprofile%\Backup_dump\"
Rem :: Just make a backup of your folder and its contents if something went wrong!
If Not Exist "%Backup_Folder%" XCopy "%Source_Folder%" "%Backup_Folder%" /D /Y /E /F >%~dp0BackupLogFile.txt
Set "VBSFILE=%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" & Call :CreateVBS
Set "TmpFile=%Temp%\%~n0.tmp"

for /R "%Source_Folder%" %%f in (*.txt) do (
    echo( ------------------------------------------
    echo  Replacing Contents of "%%f"
    echo( ------------------------------------------
    Call :Search_Replace "%%f" "%TmpFile%"
    Move /Y "%TmpFile%" "%%f">nul
)

Timeout /T 2 /NoBreak>nul & Exit
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:CreateVBS
(
    echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Function Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Dim strPattern, strReplace, strResult,oRegExp
    echo Data = "%~1" 
    echo Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll
    echo strPattern = "[\\\/\/]"
    echo strReplace = " "
    echo Set oRegExp = New RegExp
    echo oRegExp.Global = True 
    echo oRegExp.IgnoreCase = True 
    echo oRegExp.Pattern = strPattern
    echo strResult = oRegExp.Replace(Data,strReplace^)
    echo Search_Replace = strResult
    echo End Function
)>"%VBSFILE%"
Exit /b 
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Search_Replace <InputFile> <OutPutFile>
Cscript //nologo "%VBSFILE%" < "%~1" > "%~2"
Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Great!, this work as expected but it also read the  *.err file which it should NOT be picked from this loop. Please help. because in some cases file name like : abc_1234.txt-01122019.000001. and also files are not copying from source folder to back folder. please help

Comment: @Karun What did you mean by *.err file it's unclear for me !!! please explain more this what represents is it a file name or  something in the contents of the file ??

Comment: Source folder consists of error files and new files and error file like abc_1234.txt-01122019.00001.err this file we should not read and replace. So, I need to read only new files in the source folder but file extension is not fixed for new files but for error files, the extension is fixed. So, file like *.err should not be read from the bat file

Comment: So you want to read and replace in all files that have *.err in their extensions ?  You Can enconter for example a file that have this form abc_123.txt.err ? I mean double extensions ?

Comment: Nooooo!!! I dont want to read the files that have *.err in their extensions. Rest of the files I have to read.

Answer (score 0):

@Karun I think you better try for some bash script instead of bat.

You can use `SED` [Stream Editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) to search and replace characters from file.

Example:

```
sed -i 's#\\##g' sample.txt # This will replace back slash from sample.txt
sed -i 's#/##g' sample.txt # This will replace forward slash from sample.txt
```

To execute for multiple files in a directory, you can use `for` loop as well.
Save all your string replacement commands to a bash script like `test.sh` and execute it using `for` loop.

Example:

```
sed -i 's#\\##g' $1
sed -i 's#/##g' $1
```

Add above lines in test.sh and run below line of script.

```
for file in $(ls -l /home/abc/*.txt | awk '{print $NF}'); do bash test.sh $file; done
```

Comment: window bat is the requirement I have. please help